# How to toggle class after 100vh scroll

Tags: javascript, scroll, height, viewport

How to make this function add the class after scrolling `100vh`?
Currently it adds the class after `850px`.

```
$("document").ready(function($){
    var nav = $('#verschwinden');

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 850) {
            nav.addClass("doch");
        } else {
            nav.removeClass("doch");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(document)` ? or even shorter: `jQuery(function($){`

Comment: I dont know, that is what i found in the internet and it works.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In pure JavaScript use `window.innerHeight` to get the viewport height, and `elScrollable.scrollTop` to get the scrollTop of your element.
Use `classList.toggle("className", statement)` to toggle a class:

```js
const elScrollable = document.querySelector("html")
const elNav = document.querySelector("#nav");

const handleNav = () => {
  const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
  const scrollTop = elScrollable.scrollTop;
  elNav.textContent = `Scrolled: ${scrollTop / viewportHeight}`
  elNav.classList.toggle("is-active", scrollTop >= viewportHeight);
};

addEventListener("scroll", handleNav)
addEventListener("resize", handleNav)
handleNav();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
}

#nav.is-active {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">NAV</nav>
<p style="min-height: 300vh">
  scroll down until #nav becomes golden...
</p>
```

Using jQuery use `$(window).height()` to get the viewport height, and `$scrollable.scrollTop()` to get how much you scrolled the HTML (or any other) element.
Use `.toggleClass("className", statement)` to toggle a class:

```js
const $window = $(window);
const $scrollable = $("html");
const $nav = $("#nav");

const handleNav = () => {
  const viewportHeight = $window.height();
  const scrollTop = $scrollable.scrollTop();
  $nav
    .text(`Scrolled: ${scrollTop / viewportHeight}`)
    .toggleClass("is-active", scrollTop >= viewportHeight);
};

$window.on("scroll", handleNav)
$window.on("resize", handleNav)
handleNav();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

#nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
}

#nav.is-active {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav">NAV</nav>
<p style="min-height: 300vh">
  scroll down until #nav becomes golden...
</p>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice it works! But i have forget that the Naviagtion took also 6vh, is there some way to remove the height oft the navigation from the windows height?

Comment: 6 viewport height is 6% sry

Comment: could anybody write this in pure js plz?

Comment: @mh-firouzjah edited with a JS example and a more general code.